# With SQL Server, how can I update all rows but each one differently based on subquery

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Here's an example table:

```
BookID PK int
Book varchar(50)
Author varchar(50)
Sales int
```

I want to update the sales count all at once, but based on a subquery.

```
UPDATE BookTable SET Sales = (
  -- Mixture of T-SQL and pseudo code
  SELECT COUNT(SaleID) FROM BookSalesTable
  WHERE LiveMode = 1
  AND BookID = for each...
)
```

So you can see my hang up. I've done this before and just for the life of me can't recall how. I'd rather not create a temp table as I'm pretty sure it's handled in the update just fine. So I need to update the count of all the rows based on each BookID, as each one will be different. Can this be done without looping?

Comment: Use a FROM clause and correlate your subquery to the from clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An example of my comment above:

```
UPDATE bt
SET Sales = (
  SELECT COUNT(SaleID) FROM BookSalesTable bst
  WHERE bst.LiveMode = 1
  AND bst.BookID = bt.BookID
)
FROM BookTable bt
```

Answer (score 4):

```
UPDATE B 
 SET B.Sales = BS.Sales
FROM BookTable B INNER JOIN
      (SELECT BookID , COUNT(*) AS Sales  
       FROM BookSalesTable
       WHERE LiveMode = 1
       GROUP BY BookID )BS
ON B.BookID = BS.BookID
```

Comment: This was correct as well, but came in after the previous answer and didn't realize it. I wish I could mark more than one answer correct. Is there an argument as to why this answer is better than the other? Just curious of the logic difference between the two. Thank you!

Comment: This answer executes the sub-query and joins the result set of inner query to the outter query and make updates, where as Tab Alleman's answer is using a correlated sub-query, the inner query gets executed for each row returned by the outter, a good DBA will not let this code make it to production environment :) just saying

Comment: I see, so it's much better optimized as it's treated as a join, and updates against that result. Tab's query is executing the sub query for every row. Am I understanding correctly?